# How can I cut a list from given index

Tags: python, list, slice

Cut down the same list into given index

Let's say we have a list

```
mainList = [3,5,2,7,0,9]
```

If I remove 3 item
then `mainList` should be

```
[7,0,9]
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `mainList = mainList[3:]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the first n occurences in a list:

```
mainList = [3,5,2,7,0,9]
for i in range(0,3):
    mainList.pop(0)
print(mainList)
```

Output:

```
[7, 0, 9]
```